# How should I add environment properties to my JUnit5 Spring MVC integration test?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-test, junit5

I'm writing integration tests using `MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup()` in JUnit 5.

I'm extending with Sam Brannen's `SpringExtension` and a `MockitoExtension`. (Really, I'm using the composed SpringJUnitJupiterWebConfig)

I get this output when running the tests (edited):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.myapp.config.SomeConfig]; 
Could not resolve placeholder 'someEnvVar' in string value "classpath:/com/example/myapp/config/${someEnvVar}/custom.properties"
```

(This is in an internal company library on which my application depends.)

Seems clear that I need to set the environment property before the container starts up. But I'm struggling to discover how to hook into that with JUnit5.
I want to add PropertySources to the environment, I assume, but to get the environment, I have to get the application context, and in so doing, it instantiates, erroring out before I can do anything with it.

I tried creating my own extension and getting a handle to the environment during the `BeforeAllCallback`.

I'm getting the feeling that I'm going about it all wrong and I'm missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to use the `@TestPropertySource` annotation on my test class.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, b/c I was just about to say that's all you need to do. ;)

Comment: Thanks :) A more interesting question coming up. (I hope)